# Exception: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError is never thrown in the method

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley. In there I have added a method `getParams()`. But `AuthFailureError` is getting grayed, when I type `return params` in the body. Due to which I am unable to save data in the database. I am using Wamp server. I have googled a lot but no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0pcd.png)

Comment: I don't think it's due to `AuthFailureError` graying out. Did you check `onErrorResponse()` method for the error message? And also you're using Wamp server with Android. The Wamp server might be blocking requests from Android. The question can be answered if you check `onErrorResponse()` method and [edit] the question to post error message here.

Comment: i have added a new image. Kindly have a look.

Comment: As I can see you're ignoring error messages from API in `onErrorResponse()` method. There should be an error message which help you to identify the actual problem. Please log the error messages using `Log.e("TAG", "Error " + error.getMessage());`. And also do not post screenshot of code in StackOverflow. It's hard to check code in screenshot. Post only [mcve] do not post complete code here. If we need any clarification from your side, we'll let you know.